# What part of speech? --He arrived __moments__ later

Tags: parts-of-speech

> He arrived **moments** later.

Here *moments* is noun and clearly *later* must be adverb, then how is it modifying the noun?

Comment: Did you look up *later* in the dictionary?  What part of speech does it say *later* is?

Comment: When you see a sentence, "I arrived moments/a few minutes/a few hours/a few days ago", what part of speech you don't understand?

Comment: I have clearly stated my question as you can see @Rathony

Comment: I think you need to read more English sentences with adverbs and adverbial phrases and noun phrases. What makes you think later modifies moments? **Later as an adverb** should modify a verb because there is no adjective after later to modify.

Comment: @Rathony I was just speculating. I don't understand the reason behind your hostile attitude against me at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you've got it backward: *moments* modifies *later*.

> How much later? —***moments*** later.

More commonly we see expressions like *moments* (*CGEL* calls them *measure phrase modifiers*) with a specific quantifier—***some*** moments later, ***three*** hours later ; the bare plural noun leaves the exact quantity vague but in effect provides a scale by which the lateness may be measured.

This illustrates an important point: part-of-speech (or as we now say, 'word class') has only limited usefulness for describing how a particular word is used in a particular context. We are taught when we're just beginning grammatical analysis that words 'belong' in a particular category which dictates how they can be used; but eventually we reach a point where the categories break down. I'm sure you're familiar with "verbs" being used as "nouns" (***Playing*** video games is fun) "nouns" being used as "adjectives" (***street*** corner, ***office*** manager) and "adjectives" being used as "verbs" (*First you have to **brown** the meat*); here you have a noun used as an adverb. English does this sort of thing all the time.

Comment: You left me more confused! how  can noun modify adverb? Thanks

Comment: @Debanil I've added a paragraph.

Comment: @Debanil - It works because "moments" is a noun, but it's quantifying an amount.  Not just *later*, but *this much later*.  It's not that "a noun modifies an adverb", exactly, but the entire thing ("moments later") forms an [adverbial phrase](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adverbial_phrases.htm).

Comment: Really? Mr Stoney. You're my most revered poster on here, I can't believe you just said *a noun used as an adverb* .... :(